# Japanese Input Methods with Kana on the Top

Tags: discussion

I would like to know whether there is a way to input Japanese with Kana on every Kanji, like what we see sometimes on Japanese book.

Is there a input method for this? Is it supported in iOS?

Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI, these Kana are called ふりがな or ルビ.

Comment: In what location do you want to display furigana? For posts here, see: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/   For writing in Word documents or other webpages, etc, the answer would be different.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much an input method -- all you're doing is adding furigana at the top (the kanji with furigana aren't specific codepoints). Some software supports it, such as ms office, but for the most part it depends on the program. It isn't possible to input Kanji with furigana, only to add them above if the program you're using allows it.

If you're asking about how to do it on SE, then I can help more. Write the kanji on its own (e.g. 龍). Then, after the kanji in post view, add "{りゅう}". Use curly braces, and but the furigana you want to add between the braces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Being slightly more specific, the Furigana extensions are only installed here on Japanese and on [Anime](http://anime.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange. Additionally, if anyone wants to use the Furigana extensions on their own website, they can subject to [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) from https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Office software, yes.

Ex : Word 2010 ( Japanese ) https://kie.nu/2piT

You can find a button next to the eraser-like button, like ア亜. You can use the ルビ for you. ( Please compare it to English version. )

For Excel, click the right button on the cell of your choice and then 3rd from the bottom, you can find a same kind of the function ( I'm afraid I can not take a picture. )

Thanx.